# Finding maximum surface area for given length Variational Calc

Tags: calculus-of-variations

To find maximum surface area for given arc length on a surface of revolution using cylindrical coordinates, we have to optimize

$$∫2π r \sqrt{dr^2+dz^2}+c1∫\sqrt{dr^2+dz^2+(rdθ)^2}$$

with Lagrangian form on $z$ as independent variable along symmetry axis :

$$ r \sqrt{1+\left(\dfrac{dr}{dz}\right)^2} −c ∫\sqrt{1+\left(\dfrac{dr}{dz}\right)^2 +\left(\dfrac{r d\theta}{dz}\right)^2}$$

EDIT1:

Let   $\dfrac{ r d \theta }{ds}= \sin \psi  $ and we have two constants respectively  $\theta $, z basis.

$$ k_1=r \sin \psi,\quad k_2=\cos \phi\; (r- a \cos \psi)$$

in which the first invariant is known correct as Clairaut's constant and the second one is wrong.

Appreciate help to correctly obtain first integral  Euler-Lagrange equation for with two or more independent variables.